# Compare 2 json file and delete object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, local-storage

I have 2 JSON files: **A** which is on a remote server, and **B** which is in local storage.

I'd like, on page load, for jQuery to compare both files and, if an object is in the **B** file, but not in **A**, for the object to be removed from local storage.

```
var fileA = '[{"ID":"1","foo":"bar"},{"ID":"3","foo":"bar"}]'; //Remote file
var fileB = '[{"ID":"2","foo":"bar"},{"ID":"3","foo":"bar"}]'; //localStorage

var jsonA = JSON.parse(fileA);
var jsonB = JSON.parse(fileB);
jsonA.forEach(function(allA) {
  jsonB.forEach(function(allB) {
    if (allA.ID != allB.ID) {
      var i = jsonB.findIndex(mydata => mydata.ID === allA.ID);
      if (i !== -1) {
        jsonB.splice(i, 1);
        if (jsonB.length === 0) {}
        localStorage.setItem('panier', JSON.stringify(jsonB));
      }
    }
  })
})
```

What I'm trying to do is delete `ID:2` from local storage because it's not in **A**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this code below:

Tips: Avoid using `nested forEach loop` to increase efficiency.

```js
var fileA = '[{"ID":"1","foo":"bar"},{"ID":"3","foo":"bar"}]';//Remote file
var fileB = '[{"ID":"2","foo":"bar"},{"ID":"3","foo":"bar"}]'; //localStorage

var jsonA = JSON.parse(fileA);  
var jsonB = JSON.parse(fileB);  

// Temporary array to hold all id in file a
var arrA = [];
//Push all id in file A to arrA
jsonA.forEach(a => {
    arrA.push(a.ID);
});

jsonB.forEach((b,index) => {
    // check if arrA has b.ID
    if (arrA.indexOf(b.ID) == -1){
        jsonB.splice(index,1)
    }
})
console.log(jsonB)

localStorage.setItem('panier', JSON.stringify(jsonB));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```js
var fileA = '[{"ID":"1","foo":"bar"},{"ID":"3","foo":"bar"}]';//Remote file
var fileB = '[{"ID":"2","foo":"bar"},{"ID":"3","foo":"bar"}]'; //localStorage

var jsonA = JSON.parse(fileA);  
var jsonB = JSON.parse(fileB);

jsonB = jsonB.filter((o) => jsonA.findIndex((obj)=> obj.ID === o.ID)!=-1 );
console.log(jsonB);
```